# Does a virtual keyword with operator()() make sense? (functors)

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, functor

Consider I have a hierarchy defined as below

```
class Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void Run();
};
class StrategyA : public Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void Run();
};
class StrategyB : public Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void Run();
};
```

I was wondering if I replace the Run() with operator() makes any sense and if there are any advantages from a design and efficiency perspective.

```
class Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void operator()();
};
class StrategyA : public Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void operator()();
};
class StrategyB : public Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void operator()();
};
```

Thanks

CV.

Comment: mmm... don't forget the virtual destructor!

Comment: @ereOn : not exactly. It will remain virtual when accessed as an object of base class. If child classes themselves have grand-child classes and objects are accessed as child classes, the method will not behave as virtual.

Comment: @Benoit No, ereOn is right. When overriding a virtual function it makes no difference if `virtual` is used or not. (I would still recommend putting it in because it's clearer to the reader.)

Comment: Waow. My knowledge base is shaking. I was absolutely of what i was saying ! Oh well my bad. :-(

Comment: There is no (real) difference than virtual named functions, but since you intend using it with generic algorithms, why do you make them polymorphic? Generic algorithms don't use polymorphism, they freely copy your function objects based on their static type.

Comment: @Gene: I need polymorphism because I am passing the generic algorithm interface around. In this case the base class "Strategy"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Its fully makes sense.

Any operator overload is a function, after all. It adds syntactic sugar to the language. Sometimes, they're *necessary*, but often, it's just syntactic sugar.

Note that you've to invoke it polymorphically (of course, if you want runtime-polymorphism), and there're two ways you can do that:

- using *pointer* of base type, and
- using *reference* of base type

Example ([demo](http://ideone.com/2co3q)),

```
struct A
{
   virtual void operator()() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};
struct B : A
{
   virtual void operator()() { cout << "B" << endl; }
};

int main() {
        B b;

        //using pointer
        A *ptr = &b;
        (*ptr)(); //clumsy!  - prints B

        //using reference
        A &ref = b;
        ref();   //better    - prints B

        //also correct
        b();  //prints B
        return 0;
}
```

And if you've a function template written as:

```
template<typename Functor>
void call(Functor fun)
{
   (*fun)();
}
```

Then you can use this function, for functors and regular functions, both:

```
void regular_function()
{
   cout << "regular_function" << endl;
}

B b;
call(&b);  //prints B
call(regular_function); //prints regular_function
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/B9w16

Comment: So can this still be used as a regular functor?

Comment: @blueskin: Yes and No, both. Yes, you can call the functor just like regular functor (non-polymorphically). No, if you want polymorphism, as you've to use either *pointer* or *reference* as explained in my edited answer.

Comment: Yep, I was writing the same code to test it. So to add a little more, is it possible to use 'ref' in your code as a function pointer to another function 'void print(void (*ptr)())'.

Comment: @blueskin: I didn't understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: My bad, I got it, never mind :D. Thanks for the code and answer

Answer (score 5):

As has been said, yes you can.

*Additional information below towards a possible tie-breaker.*

In the case of virtual methods, you will have access to objects typed as Strategy& or Strategy*. If you are using references and not pointers, you don't need to read the following. Otherwise, it might be of interest and in favor of the named virtual method.

```
StrategyA sA;
Strategy& s = sA;

s.Run(); //correct and readable
s(); //just as correct and readable

Strategy* ptr_s = &sA;
ptr_s->Run(); //correct and readable
(*ptr_s)(); // still correct but a bit clumsy
```

Comment: well, the last statement looks clumsy but when used with STL algorithms it looks better than using Run() with bind

Comment: @blueskin : true. Now i guess you have all the information you need to choose :)

Comment: Note that you can also call `ptr_s->operator()();` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Do whatever makes your code the clearest. Generic algorithms which can accept functors could work with the second approach - so it makes sense, however balance that with readability.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `operator()` is just special function name. It can also be `virtual` as `Run()` is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. Except in specific contexts `Run` as a function name doesn't say much and if your classes mostly model functions it would seem a reasonable choice.